# How to find an invalid character or symbol inside a string

Tags: java, string, eclipse, exception, try-catch

I'm creating a program that prints user details, first the user inputs their details and then the program correctly formats the details and prints them inside a formatted box. I want the program to read strings and see if the users have entered invalid characters. For example the code below requests for the users first name:

```
// this code below is used to find the largest string in my program, ignore if this wont interfere 

String fname = scan.nextLine(); //main scan point.
//below is used to calculate largest string inputted by the user. 
int input = 0;

int fnamelength1 = fname.length();

input = fnamelength1;
int longest = 0;
if(input > longest)
    longest = input;
```

If at this point the user enters @~~NAME~~@ as their name, the program currently allows that... I want to make the program read what the user has inputted and print a message if their input isn't correct for example contains invalid symbols.

EDIT:

I'm considering anything other than characters in the alphabet as invalid... any numbers or symbols would therefore be invalid.

VALID:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Also valid:

```
' - .
```

Comment: *what* have you tried? *Where* is the effort that you put in this problem?

Comment: What symbols are considered valid ?

Comment: I'm considering anything other than characters in the alphabet as invalid... any numbers or symbols.

Comment: Bear in mind that names may contain some other symbols, e.g _O'Connor_ , _Strauss-Kahn_ .

Comment: Berger has made a valid point, I have since edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using regular expressions with the [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method. Here you define a pattern and if the string matches your pattern then it can be considered valid:

```
String fname;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean invalidInput;
do{
    System.out.println("Enter a valid name");
    fname = scan.nextLine();
    invalidInput = fname.matches("[^a-zA-Z'-]]");

    if(invalidInput){
        System.out.println("That's not a valid name");
    }

}while (invalidInput);

System.out.println("Name: " + fname);
```

**EDIT**

With String.matches we can't make a global search of invalid characters (what we want in this case). So is better using [Matcher.find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) for this:

```
String fname;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean invalidInput;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z'\\-\\s]");

do{
    System.out.println("Enter a valid name");
    fname = scan.nextLine();
    invalidInput = pattern.matcher(fname).find();

    if(invalidInput){
        System.out.println("That's not a valid name");
    }
}while (invalidInput);

System.out.println("Name: " + fname);
```

This time the pattern will validate any invalid character anywhere in the string.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and has worked since I just implemented an edited version. Thank you.

Comment: Just found a problem where if you enter the invalid name twice, it skips to the next line of code, therefore accepting the incorrect name.

Comment: Tested with user input: @@@

Comment: the edited version works perfect! Thank you. - Tested multiple times with more than one invalid symbol/character.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use regular expressions, along with the `String.matches()` method.

As an example:

```
String fname;
... some code to get fname ...
boolean valid = fname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
```

`valid` should be true if and only if `fname` is a String containing alphabetic characters, and not empty.

If empty strings are also valid, then:

```
 boolean valid = fname.matches("[a-zA-Z]*");
```

Look up the Java class [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for other variations.